# Trying to understand the syntax of this video

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to follow this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSBx9_eddmo) that teaches how to inserting data to database with Visual Studio C#. The place I'm stuck on is the syntax in the string Query (you'll know what I'm mean when seeing the video).  The code can be seen at the 5:36 mark.  I'm confused by the single, double quotes and the + sign in the portions after values (....  Are + signs required in the parameter, or they are used to concatenate.  Please help this novice who is trying to learn the language of C#.  Much appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
string Query="insert into database.edata (Eid,name,surname,age) values('"+this.Eid_txt.Te...
```

Comment: You'd have much better response if you include the syntax that's confusing you instead of forcing us to watch a video.

Comment: Never going to happen... want an answer type it in the web site.

Comment: Not many people will watch an entire training video to help you. You might want to watch the video and post it to your question in code.

Comment: Requires watching a video to answer the question

Comment: A basic understanding of strings in C# is what you need to have. The video is nothing special.

Comment: To the downvoters: I've added the portion of the string I could see from watching the video for a few seconds.

Comment: I believe this syntax is how to property create an SQL injection vulnerability

Comment: @Latex Person - This is a horrible tutorial. Coding this way will make you apps vulnerable to hacking. I'd advise googling for parameterized querying and staying away from this tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, my bad about making you guys watching the video.  I was hoping you can just go to the mark.  I didn't want to mistype the code and make the question even more confusing.  I apologize.

Comment: Ok lets not kill this guys rep over him not knowing the SO protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Ok.  The insert statement is this (a bit simplified since I cannot see the rest in the video):

```
"insert into database.edata (Eid) values ('"+this.Eid_txt.Text + '")";
```

The + sign is used for concatenation of the strings.  The single quotes are required as a part of T-SQL to quote the strings. The double quote is to end the C# string and concatinate it and the value of the text box.

That being said, this is an outdated method of doing this.  You should be using Sql parameters instead of concatinating strings this way.